Increment column based upon another column
In an Excel spreadsheet, which spans several years but has a row for every date, we have two columns-week number and week number overall. Obviously, the first column is reset to 1 at the beginning of each year but the second column just keeps going 53, 54, 55 et cetera.
The formula in Excel is simple:
=IF(I727=I726,J726,J726+1)  

Column I = week number, Column J = week number overall.
Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to generate the same data, using a SQL statement!
Can anybody advise?
Thanks

Databases aren't spreadsheets. What you seem to be asking is a Calendar table which can be easily created for 10 or 20 years in advance, with prepopulated fields for years, months, days, weekdays, week numbers, quarters, semesters or any other reporting period or label you need. There's no reason to manually increment anything once the Calendar table is created

I have been asked by my manager to recreate what was in the spreadsheet.

Then export the data into a spreadsheet and then treat it like a spreadsheet. SQL Server is not a spreadsheet; your manager asking you to treat it like one demonstrates their lack of understanding.

@Wheels496 the cost of replicating the Excel sheet is not just multiple of times larger than running Aaron Bertrand's script (lately, StackOverflow's DBA). The performance of queries that calculate dates instead of using indexed calendar tables will be a lot less

@Wheels496 if you really, really want to generate dates on the fly, you'll find a lot of SO answers that show how to use eg SQL Server's GENERATE_SERIES or sys.objects to generate sequences of number and then generate dates and labels using DATEADD(d,generated_num,some-base_address). Nobody tries to use expressions like the one you posted. The week number itself can be generated with DATEPART(wk,date). The day of year with DATEPART(dy,date)

Nitpik, they aren't called "fields". Tables have rows and columns, but not "fields".

You might also be able to use the DENSE_RANK() function as in DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Year, Week) AS OverallWeek. See this db<>fiddle for a demo using two variations of weeks - calendar weeks, which may have short weeks at the start or end of the year, and ISO weeks, which are always 7 days and may sometimes span year boundaries. As suggested earlier, this would be best loaded into a Calendar table that can be joined to your data table. Tell your manager that all the experts say "Databases aren't spreadsheets and should not be treated as such."

One more alternative is to use ISO-8601 style "yyyyWww" identifiers instead of an integer. The advantage is that this is independent of the start date of your data.  You still need to consider whether to use calendar weeks, which may have short weeks at the start or end of the year, or ISO weeks, which are always 7 days long, but may sometimes span year boundaries. The start/end of the week should also be reviewed (typically Sunday-Saturday in the US, often Monday-Sunday elsewhere, and sometimes Saturday-Friday for labor tracking).

Possible near to recreate what was in the spreadsheet
select DateColumn,WeekNumber 
  ,1+sum(case when WeekNumber<>PrevWeekNumber then 1 else 0 end)
       over(order by DateColumn) ContinuousWeekNumber
from (
  select DateColumn
     ,DATEPART(WEEK, DateColumn) AS WeekNumber
     ,DATEPART(WEEK, lag(DateColumn,1,DateColumn)over(order by DateColumn)) AS PrevWeekNumber
  from YourTable
)t

This works when (gaps in DataColumn)<(1 week)
Demo

try:
WITH DateWithRowNumber AS (
    SELECT 
        DateColumn,
        DATEPART(WEEK, DateColumn) AS WeekNumber,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(DateColumn), DATEPART(WEEK, DateColumn)) AS ContinuousWeekNumber
    FROM 
        YourTable
)
SELECT
    DateColumn,
    WeekNumber,
    ContinuousWeekNumber
FROM 
    DateWithRowNumber
ORDER BY 
    DateColumn;

result:


See player0 approach in example
